# JQuery Post Ajax call with Razor Arugment

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

Not sure if what I am trying to accomplish is possible but what I am trying to do is make a JQuery Ajax call with a Razor variable as an argument.  Here is my javascript:

```
function CreateFederationCookie() {
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/misc/create-federation-cookie",
        data: { User: '@User' },
        datatype: "json",
        success: "Success"
    });
}
```

I have the following in my Misc api controller:

```
[ActionName("create-federation-cookie")]
public void CreateFederationCookie()
{
    DAL.CreateFederationCookie(User);
}
```

Is something like this possible? It doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: There's no issues with the JS, however you've not set any parameters for ModelBinding on the `CreateFederationCookie()` endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller needs to know that it should accept a User parameter.

```
[ActionName("create-federation-cookie")]
public void CreateFederationCookie(User user)
{
    DAL.CreateFederationCookie(user);
}
```

Comment: Of course, that makes sense.  Rookie mistake, thanks.